# The cylinder of maximum volume that can be drilled from a sphere of given radius

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

> Find the dimensions of the cylinder whose maximum volume can be drilled from a steel sphere of radius 8.

As Amanda Kelius said, my problem is how to setup the expression for the volume. I know that $V = \pi r^2h$. The question is, which values are constant and which values are variable in the problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome on Math SE! Can you write what you tried so far or where you got stuck? This makes it easier to help you.

Comment: @MattAllegro I believe the OP does not know how to setup the expression for the volume. V = $\pi r^2 h$. I believe his question is, which values are constant and which values change?

Answer (score 2):

In the formula $V=\pi r^2h$, only the $\pi$ and the $2$ are constants. We choose either $r$ or $h$ to be our independent variable. I choose $h$, so $r$ and $V$ will be functions of $h$.

To find those functions, use this diagram, viewing the cylinder in the sphere from the side:

[image: Cylinder in sphere]

The cylinder looks like a rectangle with height $h$ and width $2r$. The sphere's radius of $8$ is the hypotenuse of the right triangle with legs $r$ and $\frac h2$.

You can easily get the formula for $r$ in terms of $h$ from the right triangle. Substitute that into $V=\pi r^2h$ to get your final formula for the volume $V$. Calculus can then find the maximum volume.